# Recursive dictionary from list of hierarchical codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of (around 100) values like this list:

```
list = ['40201020', '45102020', '25203020', '20106020', '25301020', '40402030', '20202010']
```

I need a dictionary that

a) lists all parents for each value. The parent has one digit less (from the right):

```
child = '40201020'
parent = '4020102'
```

this format would be ideal:

```
dict['4020102parent'] = '40201020'
```

b) I need all parents of parents up to one remaining digit. So parent '4020102' gets this parent:

```
dict['4020102parent"] = '402010'
```

and

```
dict['402010parent"] = '40201'
```

etc.

c) I then need all last descendents for each parent as a list. By last descendant, I mean the 8 digit codes of the original list. So the digit '4' would have these codes:

```
dict['4children'] = ['40201020', '45102020', '40402030']
```

or:

```
dict['40children'] = ['40201020', '40402030']
```

Comment: Can you please publish a _complete_ resulting dictionary?

Comment: I think that having the parent aspect is unreasonable as in your example, it seems as if you can ask for the parent of a number that is not even in `list`, surely it would be better to just have a dictionary where each number gives the children...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will your list always contain strings and is a dictionary a requirement?  If you will always be working with strings and you are just wanting a way to find parents and children, I would suggest using python's string handling capabilities.  You could define functions `parent` and `children` like this:

```
def parent(list_item):
    return list_item[:-1]

def children(my_list, parent_str):
    children_found = []
    for item in my_list:
        if item.startswith(parent_str)
            children_found.append(item)
    return children_found
```

Then calling `parent('40201020')` would produce `'4020102'` and calling `children(my_list, '40')` would produce `['40201020', '40402030']`.  You can call parent recursively to get a string with one less item each time.

Answer (score 1):

I am still confused why you need parent dict when you can just store recursive result in a list and can use str.startswith() method :

still i have stored parentdict in dict_data you can use that :

```
list1 = ['40201020', '45102020', '25203020', '20106020', '25301020', '40402030', '20202010']

dict_data=[]
track=[]
list_2={}

def main_function(lst_1):
    for i in lst_1:
        def recursive(lst):
            parent = {}
            if not lst:
                return 0
            else:
                parent[lst[:-1] + 'parent'] = lst
                track.append(lst)
                dict_data.append(parent)


            return recursive(lst[:-1])

        recursive(i)
main_function(list1)

for recursive_unit in set(track):
    for items in list1:
        if items.startswith(recursive_unit):
            if recursive_unit not in list_2:
                list_2[recursive_unit]=[items]
            else:
                list_2[recursive_unit].append(items)

print(list_2)
```

output:

```
{'25203': ['25203020'], '25': ['25203020', '25301020'],'4': ['40201020', '45102020', '40402030'],'4510': ['45102020'], '2520302': ['25203020'], '40402030': ['40402030'], '2010602': ['20106020'], '45102020': ['45102020'], '45': ['45102020'], '253010': ['25301020'], '4020': ['40201020'], '252': ['25203020'], '20202010': ['20202010'], '20106': ['20106020'], '201060': ['20106020'],'202020': ['20202010'], '2530102': ['25301020'], '402': ['40201020'], '2010': ['20106020'], '4510202': ['45102020'], '2530': ['25301020'], '451020': ['45102020'], '2020201': ['20202010'], '404020': ['40402030'], '25203020': ['25203020'], '2': ['25203020', '20106020', '25301020', '20202010'], '20202': ['20202010'], '253': ['25301020'], '40402': ['40402030'], '451': ['45102020'], '40201020': ['40201020'], '252030': ['25203020'], '2520': ['25203020'], '40': ['40201020', '40402030'], '4040': ['40402030'], '402010': ['40201020'], '4020102': ['40201020'], '25301020': ['25301020'], '20106020': ['20106020'], '201': ['20106020'], '20': ['20106020', '20202010'], '202': ['20202010'], '40201': ['40201020'], '45102': ['45102020'], '2020': ['20202010'], '25301': ['25301020'], '4040203': ['40402030'], '404': ['40402030']}
```

Comment: I have other categories that are not hierarchical in their content. For those, I need the parent information. I just wanted to add the information from here into the same dictionary so that I can query it at the same time. Maybe I have a layer too much. But your solution is elegant.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, a dictionary where each key contains the children seems like a more reasonable idea.

To achieve this, we can loop through each element in your list (which I renamed to `l` as to not override the built-in `list()` function), and append this value to the lists of all its parents in a dictionary, `d`.

The code for the above described method would look something along the lines of:

```
d = {}
for i in l:
    for e in range(1, len(l)-1):
        d.setdefault(i[:e], []).append(i)
```

which will then allow you to do things like:

```
>>> d['4']
['40201020', '45102020', '40402030']
>>> d['40']
['40201020', '40402030']
>>> d['25']
['25203020', '25301020']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# do not use "list" as variable name (it's a python builtin)
mylist = ['2', '20', '201', '2010', '20106', '201060', '2010602']
mylist_sorted = mylist.clone()
mylist_sorted.sort()
parents = {}
children = {}
for element in mylist_sorted:
    parents[e] = []
    children[e] = []
    for subelement in [element[0:x] for x in range(1,len(element))]:
        if subelement in parents:
            parents[element].append(subelement)
            children[subelement].append(element)
print(parents)
print(children)
```

Output:

```
{'201060': ['2', '20', '201', '2010', '20106'],
 '20106': ['2', '20', '201', '2010'],
 '2010': ['2', '20', '201'],
 '201': ['2', '20'],
 '2': [],
 '2010602': ['2', '20', '201', '2010', '20106', '201060'],
 '20': ['2']}

{'201060': ['2010602'],
 '20106': ['201060', '2010602'],
 '2010': ['20106', '201060', '2010602'],
 '201': ['2010', '20106', '201060', '2010602'],
 '2': ['20', '201', '2010', '20106', '201060', '2010602'],
 '2010602': [],
 '20': ['201', '2010', '20106', '201060', '2010602']}
```